# c# XNA confused about boolean arrays TicTacToe

Tags: c#, xna

I'm making TicTac Toe with Xna to get a firmer grip on c# programming, but i can't figure out how to solve this problem: i checkif there is a winning  patern in a boolean array for player one and two  and if so the game has to stop, but it stops too if there is a row of both x's and o's. however, this doesn't aply when the pattern is vertical.
The:code(I'm using a few texture2d's one is a cross one is an "o" , two are mouse forms and one is the background

```
      using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
     using System.Linq;
        using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
     using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
   using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
     using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
        using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
      using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
     using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

     namespace TicTacToe
 {
   public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
    {
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    static int x, y;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    static bool ifinitialized = false;
    static bool player,winOne,winTwo;
    Texture2D TTTS, TTTX, TTTR, mousex, mouseo;
    Texture2D[,] whatDraw;
    SpriteFont font;
    Rectangle[,] select;
    Vector2[,] position;
    MouseState mouse = new MouseState() ;
    MouseState prevMouse = new MouseState();
    Rectangle mouseRect ;

    static bool[,] playerOne, playerTwo, total;
    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
    }
    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        mouse = Mouse.GetState();
        playerOne = playerTwo = total  = new bool[3, 3] {                         {false,false,false }, 
            { false, false, false }, { false, false, false } };
        select = new Rectangle[3, 3];
        position = new Vector2[3, 3];
        whatDraw = new Texture2D[3, 3];
        position[0, 0] = new Vector2(0, 0);
        position[1, 0] = new Vector2(162, 0);
        position[2, 0] = new Vector2(322, 0);
        position[0, 1] = new Vector2(0, 162);
        position[1, 1] = new Vector2(162, 162);
        position[2, 1] = new Vector2(322, 162);
        position[0, 2] = new Vector2(0, 322);
        position[1, 2] = new Vector2(162, 322);
        position[2, 2] = new Vector2(322, 322);

        x = 0;
        y = 0;
        this.IsMouseVisible = false;
        base.Initialize();
    }
    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        TTTS = Content.Load<Texture2D>("TTTScheme");
        TTTR = Content.Load<Texture2D>("TTTR");
        TTTX = Content.Load<Texture2D>("TTTX");
        font = Content.Load<SpriteFont>("Font");
        mouseo  = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Mouse0;");
        mousex = Content.Load<Texture2D>("mouseX;");

        while (y<3)
        {
            while (x<3)
            {
                whatDraw[x, y] = Content.Load<Texture2D>("empty");
                x++;
            }
            x = 0;
            y++;
        }
        y = 0;
    }
    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {
    }
    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if (GamePad.GetStat(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back==                ButtonState.Pressed)
            this.Exit();
        if (!ifinitialized)
        {
            select[0, 0] = new Rectangle(0, 0,TTTX.Width,TTTX.Height);
            select[1, 0] = new Rectangle(162, 0, TTTX.Width, TTTX .Height);
            select[2, 0] = new Rectangle(322, 0, TTTX .Width, TTTX .Height);
            select[0, 1] = new Rectangle(0, 162, TTTX .Width, TTTX .Height);
            select[1, 1] = new Rectangle(162, 162, TTTX .Width,  
    TTTX .Height);
            select[2, 1] = new Rectangle(322, 162, TTTX.Width,   
  TTTX .Height);
            select[0, 2] = new Rectangle(0, 322, TTTX.Width, TTTX .Height);
            select[1, 2] = new Rectangle(162, 322, TTTX .Width, 
 TTTX .Height);
            select[2, 2] = new Rectangle(322, 322, TTTX .Width, 


    TTTX .Height);
            ifinitialized = true;
        }
        prevMouse = mouse;
        mouse = Mouse.GetState();
        if (!winOne && !winTwo)
        {
            while (y < 3)
            {
                while (x < 3)
                {

                    if (select[x, y].Contains(new Point(mouse.X, mouse.Y))
 &&
                         mouse.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed &&
                         prevMouse.LeftButton == 
ButtonState.Released&&       (total[x, y] == false))
                    {
                            total[x, y] = true;

                            if (player == false)
                            {
                                playerOne[x,y] = true;
                                whatDraw[x,y] = TTTX;
                                player = true;
                            IfWona();
                        }
                            else if (player == true)
                            {
                                playerTwo[x, y] = true;
                                whatDraw[x,y] = TTTR;
                                player = false;
                            IfWonb();
                        }


                    }
                    x++;
                }
                x = 0;
                y++;
            }
            y = 0;

        }
        base.Update(gameTime);
    }
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.White);
        spriteBatch.Begin();
        spriteBatch.Draw(TTTS, new Vector2(0, 0), Color.White);
        while(y<3)
        {
            while (x < 3)
            {

                spriteBatch.Draw(whatDraw[x, y], position[x, y], Color.White);
                x++;
            }
            x = 0;
            y++;
        }
        y = 0;

        if(player==true)
        spriteBatch.Draw(mouseo, new Vector2 (mouse.X-(mouseo .Width /2),
            mouse.Y-(mouseo .Height/2)), Color.White);
        if(player== false)
            spriteBatch.Draw(mousex, new Vector2(mouse.X - (mousex.Width / 2),
                mouse.Y - (mousex.Height / 2)), Color.White);
        spriteBatch.End();
        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
    static void IfWona()
    {
        if ((playerOne[0, 0] && playerOne[1, 0] && playerOne[2, 0]) || (playerOne[0, 1] && playerOne[1, 1] && playerOne[2, 1]) ||
            (playerOne[0, 2] && playerOne[1, 2] && playerOne[2, 2]) || (playerOne[0, 0] && playerOne[1, 0] && playerOne[2, 0]) ||
            (playerOne[0, 1] && playerOne[1, 1] && playerOne[2, 1]) || (playerOne[0, 2] && playerOne[1, 2] && playerOne[2, 2]) ||
            (playerOne[0, 0] && playerOne[1, 1] && playerOne[2, 2]) || (playerOne[0, 2] && playerOne[1, 1] && playerOne[2, 0]))
        {
            winOne = true;
        }
    }
        static void IfWonb()
            {
            if ((playerTwo[0, 0] && playerTwo[1, 0] && playerTwo[2, 0]) || (playerTwo[0, 1] && playerTwo[1, 1] && playerTwo[2, 1]) ||
                (playerTwo[0, 2] && playerTwo[1, 2] && playerTwo[2, 2]) || (playerTwo[0, 0] && playerTwo[1, 0] && playerTwo[2, 0]) ||
                (playerTwo[0, 1] && playerTwo[1, 1] && playerTwo[2, 1]) || (playerTwo[0, 2] && playerTwo[1, 2] && playerTwo[2, 2]) ||
                (playerTwo[0, 0] && playerTwo[1, 1] && playerTwo[2, 2]) || (playerTwo[0, 2] && playerTwo[1, 1] && playerTwo[2, 0]))
            {
                winTwo = true;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

thanks already
a young programmer

Answer (score 0):

When I reformat your code, it looks like some of the win conditions are repeated.

```
    (playerOne[0, 0] && playerOne[1, 0] && playerOne[2, 0]) ||  // here
    (playerOne[0, 1] && playerOne[1, 1] && playerOne[2, 1]) ||
    (playerOne[0, 2] && playerOne[1, 2] && playerOne[2, 2]) || 
    (playerOne[0, 0] && playerOne[1, 0] && playerOne[2, 0]) ||  // and here
    (playerOne[0, 1] && playerOne[1, 1] && playerOne[2, 1]) || 
    (playerOne[0, 2] && playerOne[1, 2] && playerOne[2, 2]) ||
    (playerOne[0, 0] && playerOne[1, 1] && playerOne[2, 2]) || 
    (playerOne[0, 2] && playerOne[1, 1] && playerOne[2, 0]))
```

Take a look for other repeated win conditions as well.

Comment: The win conditions may be repeated, but that would not affect the result of the statement.

Comment: Even more, the second condidition is the same as the the line under your comment `// and here`. OP just seems to have not swapped the x and y coordinates, I guess these were supposed to be the checks for the vertical lines, but ended up to be checks for horizontal lines. The three lines starting at `// and here` are a repitition of the first three lines. If you swap the x and y in all these three lines, you'll get the right result.

Comment: There should be 8 *different* ways to win -- 3 horizontal, 3 vertical, and 2 diagonal.  There are duplicates in these 8 conditions.

Comment: The win condition logic is not the problem. Please see my answer.

Comment: After a glance at yours, then it looks like there are 2 problems.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the wide world of programming, LC Masters!

The code you have to check for a winner will work. The issue you are having in your code is that there is currently no distinction between `playerOne` and `playerTwo`. While it may look like you have created two separate boolean arrays for these variables, you are making a mistake on this line:

> ```
> playerOne = playerTwo = total  = new bool[3, 3] { {false,false,false }, 
>         { false, false, false }, { false, false, false } };
> ```

The problem with this line of code is that you are assigning `playerOne` to the exact same boolean array as `playerTwo`. After that line of code executes, `playerOne` and `playerTwo` become aliases of the exact same data in memory (same goes for `total`), meaning, they are two different names for the same boolean array. This would be like having a nickname that a lot of people call you by. Your name might be "Thomas" and some friends might call you "T.J.", but either way, "Thomas" and "T.J." are names that refer to the exact same person; you! Because of this problem, any move that either player performs will be seen as being done by both players simultaneously.

To fix your problem, you will need to separate the assignment for `playerOne` and `playerTwo` (and I would do the same for total), as shown in the following code:

```
playerOne = new bool[3, 3];
playerTwo = new bool[3, 3];
```

Now `playerOne` and `playerTwo` each have their own boolean array. After applying this code, you may need to make additional changes in your code to account for these two players having their own boolean arrays (for example, you don't want to allow two players to play at the same location).

As a final point, notice that when creating `playerOne` and `playerTwo` in the code above, I did not explicitly assign the values of the array to `false`, because it's not necessary. When you create a boolean array, the values of the array will default to false, as shown in the table provided [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83fhsxwc.aspx).

Again, this solution may not fix everything with your program, but it will put you closer toward completing your project. Happy coding!